# Mixing log4j 1.x and log4j 2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a new application that is being written using log4j2, to take advantage of some of its new features. One of the libraries it uses is a bit older and was built with log4j 1.x. I'm having a problem where the new code in the application writes to the log, but the code in the old library does not write to the log. I even have one class which is a subclass of something in the old library and is also called by code in the old library, and this code also will not write to the log. I have configured the application to use log4j2 version 2.0.2, and I explicitly excluded log4j when referencing the old library as a maven dependency.

How can I get the code in the old library logging into the same file as my new code?

*Re-writing the old library should be thought of as a last-resort option*

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Are you aware that log4j2 includes a bridge for log4j-1.2? You can use it by removing the old log4j-1.2.17.jar, and include these three jars:

- log4j-api-2.x.jar
- log4j-core-2.x.jar
- log4j-1.2-api-2.x.jar

This will result in all calls that your application makes to the log4-1.2 API to be routed to the log4j2 implementation. The FAQ has a [diagram](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars) that may clarify things. (Don't forget to remove the old log4j-1.2 jar from the classpath!)

Comment: It seems I was also missing `log4j-jcl`, but I've got logging working now, thanks!

Comment: Custom Log4j2 appenders: yes. Custom log4j 1.2 appenders: no.  This is an API adapter, the implementation has changed. You'll need to port custom extensions to Log4j2.

Comment: does this affect the configuration files, this means I need to migrate my log4j1 files to the syntax of log4j2 syntax ?

Comment: Yes, log4j 2 does not understand log4j1.x configuration files.

Comment: Where do we set this system property  “log4j1.compatibility” to a value of “true” as mentioned in the doc - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.13.0/manual/compatibility.html